# C programming Bus error/Seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bus

Im trying to make a program that puts a filter on a bmp file. I run it and get a bus error on a mac gcc and I get the following on a linux machine:

> 104:8: warning: variable ‘new_file’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>   159:56: warning: ‘pixel’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
>   185:10: warning: ‘bmpOut’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

When I run it I get a set fault Core Dump.

IS there anything you guys see wrong with this? I think it has to do with pointers.

Comment: Did you at least fix the warnings you were so nicely given? They seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ive tried. Im unsure of how to fix these last three. When i delete new_file i get a new error.

Comment: Any chance you can run this through a debugger?

Comment: Yes it says the follow... Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x0000000100006000
0x0000000100001484 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffc08) at :170
170                   holdRed+= Matrix[pixCounter]*pixel[holdr1*Height+holdc1].Red;

Comment: That was a gdb on the mac. Now the gdb on the linux machines says Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_fread (buf=0x7fffffffd8d0, size=2, count=1, fp=0x0) at iofread.c:43
43 iofread.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: Well, you use `fwrite` with `bmpOut` when `bmpOut` is still an uninitialized pointer, pointing to nowhere in particular, let alone a valid file. You use `pixel` like an array, despite the same thing.

Comment: Very interesting. Are you saying youd suggest me to make it a value?

Comment: I'm just saying what your warnings are saying. You're using your pointers, but they don't point to anything yet.

Comment: Oh yes that does make sense. bmpout is supposed to be the bmp picture that im outputting. How would I do something like that,I thought thats how you make a file for later use?

Comment: In the case of `bmpOut`, you have to make it point to a valid `FILE`, such as one returned by `fopen`.

Comment: So Id point it to the old bmp file then rewrite over it at the end of the program?

Answer (score 1):

> 104:8: warning: variable ‘new_file’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

This tells you that the variable `new_file` doesn't have any impact on your logic what-so-ever. It unnecessarily complicates your code; You should probably remove it. This wouldn't cause your segfaults, however. That's more likely the latter two:

> 159:56: warning: ‘pixel’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

This is a more serious problem. There is nothing to assign pixel (a pointer) to point to an object, prior to `pixel[holdr*Height+holdc]`. Before you use `pixel[...]`, you need to make sure it points to something! I suggest something along the lines of `pixel = malloc(count * sizeof *pixel);`.

> 185:10: warning: ‘bmpOut’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Again, this is pretty serious! I'd think you'd want to make tmpOut point to a file before writing to that file. I suggest something along the lines of `tmpOut = fopen("/path/to/filename", "wb");` or `tmpOut = stdout;`.

Have you considered using valgrind?

Comment: Now im getting an errorin GDB saying Program Received Signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS for the the line that reads holdRed += Matrix[pixCounter]*rgb[holdr1*Height+holdc1].Red;

Comment: How many items can Matrix store? `print pixCounter`... Which book are you reading?